# Anyway to get an indexed item from $(".box")

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I get a list of items like `$(".box")`. Is it possible to get an indexed jQuery object

like

```
var $boxes = $(".box"),
    $box2 = $boxes[1]
```

currently I do something like

```
var $boxes = $(".box");
$boxes.each(function(i, box) {
    var $box = $(box); // <-- is this a good idea?
    // do something with $box
});
```

I wonder tho if the line `var $box = $(box)` is such a good idea? I am actually running that in a `setInterval()`

like

```
var $boxes = $(".box");
setInterval(function() {
    $boxes.each(function(i, box) {
        var $box = $(box); // <-- is this a good idea?
        // do something with $box
    });
}, 1000);
```

I wonder if its bad for performance since I am initializing a variable for each item in `$boxes` per 1s in this example. If I can access the element directly from the jQuery "array" or whatever $boxes is, it maybe better?

Comment: Have you tried what you gave as an example? Actually, how are your two questions related?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate though the jQuery elements as per your example, nothing wrong with that. Creating a local variable for each element `var $box = $(box);` is a good idea.

You can also access the elements of the jQuery object with the eq method, e.g:

```
var $boxes = $(".box"),
$box2 = $boxes.eq(1);
```

That way you don't need to pass the element through the $ constructor.

Comment: *"That way you don't need to pass the element through the $ constructor."* True! But `$($boxes[1])` is *much* more direct and efficient than `$boxes.eq(1)`. Unless you're going to use `.end()`, you're better off going through `$()` than `eq()`. `eq()` hands off to `slice()` which hands off to `pushStack()` with calls to...well, let's just say it's doing a lot of work to set things up so you can do `end()`. Which is great if you need it, but unnecessary otherwise. (Not that you'll see the difference in the real world unless you're dealing with a *lot* of these.)

Answer (score 5):

It's not entirely clear what your question is, but jQuery objects are *already* array-like, you can use the `[]` operators on them. What you get back is the raw DOM object at that index, so:

```
var $boxes = $(".box"),
    box2 = $boxes[1],   // `box2` is a raw DOM object
    $box2 = $(box2);    // `$box2` is a jQuery wrapper around the second box
```

Regarding this code:

```
var $boxes = $(".box");
setInterval(function() {
    $boxes.each(function(i, box) {
        var $box = $(box); // <-- is this a good idea?
        // do something with $box
    });
}, 1000);
```

It's fine to do that provided you really need to do it (e.g., if you really need a jQuery wrapper around that specific entry). It *is* making the browser do work each time the interval timer fires (because `$()` isn't free, though it's not *expensive* either), so if the list is short, you could trade that CPU time for memory use by pre-creating the jQuery wrappers on the elements:

```
var $wrapped = [];
$(".box").each(function() {
    $wrapped.push($(this));
});
setInterval(function() {
    $.each($wrapped, function(i, $box) {
        // do something with $box
    });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a faster and more efficient way of looping through the elements while also having a jQuery wrapper for each one, check out Ben Alman's "each2" plugin:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#each2

Then you could replace this code:

```
$boxes.each(function(i, box) {
    var $box = $(box);
    // do something with $box
});
```

With this:

```
$boxes.each2(function(i, $box) {
    // do something with $box
});
```

Comment: **Very** interesting. Requires that one re-test with each dot release of jQuery (since it's mucking about with internals), but hey, you should probably do that *anyway*...

Answer (score 2):

On a side-note,

```
var $boxes = $(".box");
setInterval(function() {
    $boxes.each(function(i, box) {
        var $box = $(box);
        // do something with $box
    });
}, 1000);
```

is equivalent to

```
var $boxes = $(".box");
setInterval(function() {
    $boxes.each(function() {
        var $box = $(this);
        // do something with $box
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: True, but it's not an answer to the question. Comments should be *comments* (if you need formatting, there's always http://pastie.org, http://jsbin.com, http://jsfiddle.net, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

'i' in the callback function of each is the index. But I wouldn't recommend it. Simply call 'this' inside the each function for the current element.

var $box = this;

Comment: *"`var $box = this;`"* That will be the raw DOM element, not a jQuery wrapper. He's clearly looking to have a jQuery wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need i.e. box 3:

```
$('.box:eq(3)').doStuff();
```

Comment: Or better yet, `$('.box').eq(3).doStuff()`

Comment: @Eric: Why is that better? icc's version lets the selector engine skip ones it doesn't need and stop when the condition is satisfied. Your "better" solution requires that the selector engine find them all, and then jQuery post-filters the list. (The degree to which the selector engine can optimize will vary a lot by browser, but still, what's "better" about not giving it the chance?)

Comment: He's using *all* of them, just one at a time. Not seeing how this helps.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I was under the impression that the engine probably did the same thing as the jQuery. Admittedly, the browser could natively implement the selector, which would offer an improvement over the filtering.

Comment: @Eric: Exactly. Basically, if jQuery can take advantage of any features in the browser's native implementation at the selection stage to satisfy the condition, great. Sizzle (jQuery's engine) is pretty good at that. :-)